# How does one collect each value of specific but related entries (key-value pairs) into a single array and does assign the latter to a sole merged key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, key-value

From a database result. I got a response like

```
[
  {
    id: 11544,
    emp_code: "DF",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,
    emp1sk: 10151,
    emp2sk: 10151,
    emp3sk: 10052,
    emp1name: 'efraim',
    emp2name: 'andrea',
    emp3name: 'monique',
  },
  {
  ....},
  ...........
]
```

with this record how I can make a array of object like

```
[
  {
    id: 11544,
    emp_code: "DF",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,
    emp: [{
      id: 10151,
      name: 'efraim'
    }, {
      id: 10151,
      name: 'andrea'
    }, {
      id: 10052,
      name: 'monique'
    }]
  },
 , {
  ....},
  ...........
]
```

i can not change the database nor the getting response. how i can make it and also the employee is not limited to the it can be anything. how i can do that

Comment: Do you really want to keep differently-named properties, or do you actually want get `emps = [{id: 1, name: 'rick'}, {id: 2, name: 'bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'john'}]`?

Comment: Also, I recommend fixing that database instead, to use a normalised schema in the first place.

Comment: no @Bergi i can not modify database

Comment: yes i want to keep differently-named properties with a count on each field like i mentioned in my object

Comment: no @Gass it's an objects

Comment: Are property names the same for all objects in array? e.g `emp1name` `emp2name` `emp1sk` ??

Comment: yes @Gass, it's same type of object

Comment: @MradulJain ... there is a new answer with a late provided implementation which in return solves the problem of merging entries in a generic way, thus it is agnostic to object entries of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the count of emp_sk values and then use a for loop to insert sk and name in emp array and insert the rest of key-value pair as it is

```js
const q = [
  {
    id: 11544,
    emp_code: "DF",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,
    emp1sk: 10151,
    emp2sk: 10151,
    emp3sk: 10052,
    emp1name: 'efraim',
    emp2name: 'andrea',
    emp3name: 'monique'
  },
  {
    id: 11545,
    emp_code: "DS",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,
    emp1sk: 10151,
    emp2sk: 10151,
    emp1name: 'efraim',
    emp2name: 'andrea'
  }
]

console.log(
  q.map((e) => {
    const length = Object.keys(e).filter((key) => key.match('emp[0-9]+sk')).length;
    let emp = [];
    for(let i=1; i<=length; i++) {
      emp.push({id: e[`emp${i}sk`], name: e[`emp${i}name`]})
    }
    let ans = {
      id: e['id'],
      emp_code: e['emp_code'],
      date_received: e['date_received'],
      closed_ind: e['closed_ind'],
      declined: e['declined'],
      create_date: e['create_date'],
      billing_rate: e['billing_rate']
    }
    return {...ans, emp};
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The next provided approach generically solves the task of merging specific entries (key-value pairs) of any object, based on custom configurable rule sets, which get bound to the generic merge function.

Thus one always can reuse a single function like `mergeItemEntriesByBoundConfig` and just adapt the rules to ones needs.

The configuration has to feature two arrays, `skips` and `takes`.

The former ... `skips` ... will contain regex items only that each describe which of an object's key should be skipped (thus not processed).

The latter ... `takes` ... exclusively contains items that each describe which kind of entry will be *merged into a **single key***. Thus such an item features two properties, `regX` and `create`.

The regular expression identifies the to be processed entry by its `key`, whereas `create` is a function which always has to **return a *key-value pair*** of the ***merger key*** and the ***merger value** that will be pushed into the very array* which the *merger key* does refer to.

In order to always achieve this creation task in the best possible way, any `create` function gets passed the following three parameters into ... `[item, key, regX]` ... where `item` is the processed object itself, and `key` is taken from the currently processed entry, and `regX` is the regular expression which did/does match the current `key`.

```js
function mergeItemEntriesByBoundConfig(item) {
  const { takes, skips } = this;

  return Object
    .entries(item)
    .reduce((merger, [key, value]) => {
    
      let isSkip = skips.some(regX => regX.test(key));
      if (!isSkip) {

        takes.forEach(({ create, regX }) => {
          if (regX.test(key)) {

            isSkip = true;
            const [
              mergerKey,
              mergerValue
            ] = create(item, key, regX);

            (merger[mergerKey] ??= []).push(mergerValue);
          }
        });
      }
      if (!isSkip) {

        // default key-value handling.
        merger[key] = value;
      }
      return merger;

    }, {});
}

console.log([{

    id: 11544,
    emp_code: "DF",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,

    emp1sk: 10151,
    emp2sk: 10152,
    emp3sk: 10053,
    emp1name: 'efraim',
    emp2name: 'andrea',
    emp3name: 'monique',
  }, {
    id: 11545,
    emp_code: "DS",
    date_received: "2000-10-18",
    closed_ind: "C",
    declined: null,
    create_date: "2000-10-18",
    billing_rate: null,

    emp1sk: 10151,
    emp2sk: 10152,
    emp1name: 'efraim',
    emp2name: 'andrea',

    fooX: 'baaaz',
    fooYY: 'biiz',
    fooZZZ: 'buz',
    baaaz: 'bar x',
    biiz: 'bar xx',
    buz: 'bar xxx',

  }].map(mergeItemEntriesByBoundConfig, {
    takes: [{
      create: (item, key, regX) => {

        const { link } = regX.exec(key).groups;

        // creates and returns a (merger) key-value tuple.
        return ['emp', {
          id: item[key],
          name: item[`emp${ link }name`],
        }];
      },
      regX: /^emp(?<link>\d+)sk$/,
    }, {
      create: (item, key/*, regX*/) => {

        // creates and returns a (merger) key-value tuple.
        return ['foos', item[item[key]]];
      },
      regX: /^foo\w+$/,
    }],
    skips: [/^emp\d+name$/, /b\w+z/],
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```